# Loop Through Array of Images

Tags: c#, arrays, image, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have a UI image, and I would like it to display a different image on a UI button click. I know how to loop through UI text, but not UI images. Here's what I can do with text:

```
Text text;
string[] array = {"Hi!", "Ho!", "You clicked me!"};
int num = 0;
void Start() {
    text = GetComponent<Text> ();
}
void Change() {
    num++;
    if(num == 3) {
        num = 0;
    }
    text.text = array[num];
}
```

How can I do the same thing with images?

Comment: Please find a better title to your question!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair How about that?

Comment: by far better! but: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Oh! I never knew that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can do this, I have recently implemented this in my game :

```
public class ImageHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image img;
    public List<Sprite> imageObjs;
    private Sprite activeImage;

    public void LoadLevelImage(int levelNumber)
    {
        this.activeImage = (Sprite)Instantiate(imageObjs[levelNumber - 1]);
        img.sprite = activeImage;
    }
}
```